# How to know which domain send request using JS to my C# action

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, http-referer

I need to know which domain send request to my C# action(MVC),
I get the request and return JS code,

For example:
Someone put this code in is site(http://www.ClientExampleSite.com/) :

```
<script src="http://www.MyExampleSite.com/GetDomin /GetDomin" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I need to return this code:

```
Var Domin = 'www.ClientExampleSite.com';
```

The problem is that UrlReferrer don't work in this situation.

Thanks

***edit:***
In the end what I want to do is to block requests from unknow domains.

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer`

Comment: UrlReferrer is null when the request is send from JS like the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

var domainName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority;

Or you can try,

```
var theProvider = (IServiceProvider)HttpContext;
var theWorker = (HttpWorkerRequest)theProvider.GetService(typeof(HttpWorkerRequest));
string theReferer = theWorker.GetKnownRequestHeader(HttpWorkerRequest.HeaderReferer);
```

**Updates:**
Based from your comment you can fetch client domain name from IP adress below code

```
        var clientIP = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]==null) ? System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress:
                           System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
        IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse(clientIP);
        IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(addr);
        var clientDomainName = entry.HostName;
```

Comment: I get my domain, the URL is my URL, I need to know who send the request not the url of the request.

Comment: What is the mean of "who send the request"? IP address of Client machine? and If you call action method controller from JS than you can pass current browser domain name using  window.location.href JS function

Comment: I meant to the site domain who i get the request from,
and I can't use JS to do this, the js is in the client side,
I only have Control on the server side.
I edit my post,
In the end what I want to do is to block requests from unknow domains.

Comment: Let me know is it able to solve your problem or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.ClientExampleSite.com/");   
string domain = myUri.Host;
```

Refer [Uri.Host Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx)

> Gets the host component of this instance.

or you can try this:

```
var domain =   HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
```

To get the client domain name

```
string clientDomain = string.Empty;
clientDomain = context.Request.UrlReferrer.Host;
```

Comment: It does not work, I get my domain(www.MyExampleSite.com) instead of the client domain(www.ClientExampleSite.com)

Comment: @dolevdolev:- Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: UrlReferrer don't work for the request like in the example only for regular requests.